# Parse string in the right Format to DateTime

Tags: c#, visual-studio, datetime, calendar

I have the problem, that i can't parse my string in the right format to DateTime.
I tried a lot of different ways and searched on several websites, but i didn't find a solution for my problem

```
string vonDatum = dtpVon.Value.ToString("dd.MM.yyyy");
        DateTime startDatum = DateTime.ParseExact(vonDatum, "dd.MM.yyyy", null);
        String bisDatum = dptBis.Value.ToString("dd.MM.yyyy");
        DateTime endDatum = DateTime.ParseExact(bisDatum, "dd.MM.yyyy", null);
```

As you can see, i want to parse in as dd.MM.yyyy. But i receive something like dd.MM.yyyy.ss.fff (not sure about the ss.fff, but I get also the seconds and the milliseconds back).

Thanks a lot if someone can help me

Comment: This is working fine for me, is this the exact code you tried yourself for your DateTime-Parse Try ?

Comment: Yes, my code is exactly the same. Even with just DateTime-Parse it doesn't work. I get something like {12.01.2016 00:00:00}. I think the 00:00:00 comes from the TimeOfDay Value. But i don't know how to remove this :/

Comment: You are not checking the string, you are checking the DateTime.ToString() currently, your string is "12.01.2016"

Comment: strange, because in my database it also puts the value 12.01.2016 in. Maybe i have a fault in this command: for (DateTime date = startDatum; date <= endDatum; date = date.AddDays(1))

Comment: I meant 12.01.2016 00:00:00*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just found it out by myself.
If anyone have the same problem, here is how you can handle it.

```
 string datum = String.Format("{0:dd/MM/yyyy}", date);
```

By example, I'm using it in this context.

```
string vonDatum = dtpVon.Value.ToString("dd.MM.yyyy");
        DateTime startDatum = DateTime.ParseExact(vonDatum, "dd.MM.yyyy", null);

        string bisDatum = dptBis.Value.ToString("dd.MM.yyyy");
        DateTime endDatum = DateTime.ParseExact(bisDatum, "dd.MM.yyyy", null);

 for (DateTime date = startDatum; date <= endDatum; date = date.AddDays(1))
            {
                string datum = String.Format("{0:dd/MM/yyyy}", date);
                // Erste tabellenbefüllung erstellen 
                sqlite_cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO einteilung (mitarbeiter, arbeitsschicht, datum) VALUES ('"+mitarbeiter+"', '"+arbeitsschicht+"', '"+datum +"');";
                sqlite_cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

parsing datetime into specific string format or converting it into specific culture usually throw exception. You can use the following code to get this format `dd.MM.yyyy`

```
DateTime dateString = DateTime.Now;

string day = dateString.Day.ToString();
string month = dateString.Month.ToString();
string year = dateString.Year.ToString();

string date = day + "." + month + "." + year;
Console.WriteLine(date);
```

output : 10.2.2017

Comment: Thanks for the help. Honestly I can't use you're example correctly in my application. Also I forgot to day, that I made a mistake by the creation of this post. I forgot to tell you, that I get my day/month/year information from a dateTime picker. Maybe my version doesn't work, because of that...